# CCNetIntegrationStatus is always UNKNOWN when used in the publishers section

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a build process running with CCNET v1.8.5. When the build completes, successfully or not I want to send a notification to Slack. I have the notification piece working with Slack's web hooks (see below) but I cannot seem to obtain the status of the current build via the CCNetIntegrationStatus property. The result of using `$[$CCNetIntegrationStatus]` in my config is always Unknown.

I have a hunch that the reason is that these CCNET integration properties (at least they way that I am declaring them) are processed and defined when the build starts. Of course, when the build starts the build status would be UNKNOWN.

I have also tried:

- `$[CCNetIntegrationStatus]`, the result is an empty/blank string.
- `$(CCNetIntegrationStatus)`, ccnet.config cannot be processed, variable not found
- `$CCNetIntegrationStatus`, the result is the literal string `$CCNetIntegrationStatus`

Ultimately, what I want to achieve is to send an HTTP request (notification) once the build is complete that includes the current builds integration status, the prior builds integration status, the version number, and project name. How would I go about doing this?

Here is the sample configuration:

```
<!-- block definition to send slack notification -->

<cb:define name="SlackNotificationBlock">
    <checkHttpStatus>
        <httpRequest>
            <method>POST</method>
            <uri>$(slackUrl)</uri>
            <body> {{
                      "username": "Build Bot",
                      "icon_emoji": ":build:",
                      "attachments": [
                        {{
                          "fallback": "Warning! A New Build Approaches!",
                          "pretext": "Warning! A New Build Approaches!",
                          "color": "#D00000",
                          "username": "Build Bot",
                          "icon_emoji": ":build",
                          "fields": [
                            {{
                              "title": "Project",
                              "value": "$[$CCNetProject]",
                              "short": true
                            }},
                            {{
                              "title": "Version",
                              "value": "$[$CCNetLabel]",
                              "short": true
                            }},
                            {{
                              "title": "Status",
                              "value": "$[$CCNetIntegrationStatus]",
                              "short": true
                            }},
                            {{
                              "title": "Last Status",
                              "value": "$[$CCNetLastIntegrationStatus]",
                              "short": true
                            }},
                            {{
                              "title": "Location",
                              "value": "$(appUrl)",
                              "short": false
                            }}
                          ]
                        }}
                      ]
                    }}
            </body>
            <timeout>5000</timeout>
        </httpRequest>
    </checkHttpStatus>
</cb:define>

<!-- my publishers block -->
<publishers>
    <xmllogger/>

    <cb:scope slackUrl="url-to-slack"
              appUrl="application-url">
        <cb:SlackNotificationBlock/>
    </cb:scope>

</publishers>
```

Comment: Do any of the other replacements work like `CCNetUser` or more importantly `CCNetLastIntegrationStatus`?

Comment: See this page for the syntax of in-place replacements in the configuration preprocessor: http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution via the [CCNetSlackPublisher](https://github.com/jrjackso/CCNetSlackPublisher). It accomplishes via a custom task what I was attempting to do entirely within the CCNET configuration syntax. Specifically, by implementing a custom task [CCNetSlackPublisher](https://github.com/jrjackso/CCNetSlackPublisher) is able to correctly obtain the current integration status. It then send that along to my configured slack channel. An additional benefit is that my CCNET configuration is simpler as well!

I was never able to 100% confirm my hunch that the CCNetIntegrationStatus property is evaluated once when the build starts. However, given the behavior that I was seeing I believe this to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

First I had to chuckle at the variations you tried like $(CCNetIntegrationStatus]. I mean really? But your hunch is right. The ccnet config code is static. The only way to make it dynamic is to source stuff from a file that you change during the build. This can be done with the build label but not apparently with the httpRequest.

I would do the url stuff in Nant. That gives you more flexibility. You can call it whenever you want.

Comment: It is possible to inject dynamic values, why its not resolving to a value I'm not sure just yet. See http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Direct_Dynamic_Value

Comment: Doh! The 'odd' variations were a typo in the original post. It has been fixed. Thanks for the info, I'll need to look into this further.

Comment: The dynamic values Simon talked about would be from ccnet parameters which are set at build start time. I don't think that's going to help you.

Comment: @Adam Bruss the `direct dynamic values` are there to allow you to replace any run-time parameter into a string, therefore any ccnet environment variable for the build can be injected using this technique. These are not static/constant values, the replacement happens for each build occurrence.

Comment: However, @Adam you may have stumbled on one point. If the replacement is happening at build start rather than at task execution then this would exhibit 'static' like behaviour; I'm not sure how its working at the moment. I know i have used the technique to introduce dynamic values into the build but admittedly those values were supplied at the start of the build.